# After insalling KB2846071 event.clinetY seems to be negative value

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Installation of KB2846071 breaks the event.clientX and event.clientY properties when we are in an onbeforeunload event handler.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if (event.clientY < 0 ) {
        // close the session
        // warn the user... 
    }
};
```

This fires now everytime when a user clicks a link on the page because event.clientY is always negative. That means our users are losing their sessions by clicking on links or link buttons within the app!

any solution for this is appreciated.

Regards,
Nimi

Comment: This is an exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691624/ie-why-is-event-clienty-always-negative-on-some-client-machines

Answer (score 0):

This issue affects us as well. So far it seems to affect IE9 and IE10, but not IE8.

There is an entry on this bug on Microsoft Connect and Microsoft are stating that they are investigating the issue. If there is going to be an update, it will be published there. I also recommend to "vote" on that issue.

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/794228/kb2846071-breaks-event-clientx-and-event-clienty-properties-in-onbeforeunload-event-handlers-in-ie9-and-10