# Workaround for issues with KB2846071

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Because of the patch KB2846071, we are getting issues in our web application wherever we are using `window.event.clientX` or `window.event.clientY`.

One part of this is breaking a critical functionality in our application. I have looked into some of the links as

[After insalling KB2846071 event.clinetY seems to be negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801953/after-insalling-kb2846071-event-clinety-seems-to-be-negative-value)

[Did windows update 2846071 break break the handling of window.event.clientX clientY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604229/did-windows-update-2846071-break-break-the-handling-of-window-event-clientx-clie/17625107#17625107)

But none of these provide any solution or workaround. I know solution would be something from MS, but right now we are looking for immidiate fix. Can anyone provide something that I can use in place of below code?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if (event.clientY < 0 ) {
        // close the session
        // warn the user... 
    }
};
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with jQuery. Why not use jQuery?

Comment: will jquery not internally use this same property?

Comment: jQuery is cleverly written to normalise functionality across browsers. You may find that the way they've written it makes your problem go away. I did say **may**!

Comment: @Guanxi Maybe if you explain the use case for this someone might come up with a workaround.